# Vega transformation to calculate average time lengths

Tags: statistics, transform, vega-lite, vega

I am wondering if the following transformation is possible in Vega.

Imagine we have data points that represent tasks and each task is characterized by two properties.

- **date_opened**  - a date when the task was created - this is always defined
- **date_closed** - a date when the task was closed - this is defined if the task has been closed or null for pending tasks.

I would like to get a metric with an average task execution time at the end of a day (or a different time unit: week/month etc.)
The catch is I want to take into account both completed tasks and tasks that are still pending at the end of a given day.

Let's see an example - given the following data:

```json
[
  { "id": 1, "date_opened": "2021-01-02 10:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-02 12:00"},
  { "id": 2, "date_opened": "2021-01-04 10:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-04 14:00"},
  { "id": 3, "date_opened": "2021-01-04 12:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-06 12:00"},
  { "id": 4, "date_opened": "2021-01-06 12:00", "date_closed": null}
]
```

the calculation would be as follows

| date | result | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | 2 hours | task 1 was completed in 2 hours |
| 2021-01-03 | 0 hours | no tasks |
| 2021-01-04 | 8 hours | task 2 completed in 4 hours, task 3 still pending at the end of the day for the total of 12 hours; (4 + 12)/2 = 8 |
| 2021-01-05 | 36 hours | task 3 still pending at the end of the day for the total of 36 hours |
| 2021-01-06 | 30 hours | task 3 closed after 48 hours, task 4 pending for 12 hours at the end of the day; (48 + 12)/2 = 30 |
| 2021-01-07 | 36 hours | task 4 still pending for the total of 36 hours |
| 2021-01-08 | 60 hours | task 4 still pending for the total of 60 hours |

This looks like a very useful metric for a variety of scenarios: tasks, order deliveries, process runtimes, etc.
I can do that server-side but since my chart has a signal to control the time unit (day, week, month, etc.) it would make sense to the transform in Vega.
Note that doing the calculation efficiently requires some smarts, such as using an interval tree.

Answer (score 1):

Vega can create chart of aggregate statistics (count, average hours or total hours) for all tasks by date.

For input that includes only start and end dates for each task, Vega will need to:

1. Generate array of dates for each task ("[formula](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/formula/)" transform with "[timeSequence()" or "utcSequence()](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#datetime-functions)"
2. Generate separate data records for each date by task ("[flatten](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/flatten/)" transform)
3. Create aggregate statisitcs using the data ("[aggregate](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/aggregate/)" transform)

Here is a complete working example in CodePen (html, css and javascript) using utc datetime. This implementation includes (in javascript) a Vega expression function "utcFloor" that calls the Vega API function "utcFloor".

[View in CodePen](https://codepen.io/RoyIng/pen/GROOJPZ)

https://codepen.io/RoyIng/pen/GROOJPZ

[image]

```
    vega.expressionFunction("utcFloor", function(units, date){
    return vega.utcFloor(units)(date);     
    });

let vegaSpec = {
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
"description": "Vega 5 chart: Example of task statistics by date",
"width": 500,
"height": 400,
"padding": 5,
"autosize": {"type": "fit", "resize": true, "contains": "padding"},
"signals": [
    {
    "name": "signal_aggregate_type",
    "value": ["Number of tasks"],
    "bind": {
        "input": "select",
        "name": "Measure: ",
        "options": [
        "Number of tasks",
        "Average hours per task",
        "Total hours for all tasks"
        ]
    }
    },
    {
    "name": "signal_track_interval_input",
    "update": ["2020-12-25", "2021-01-10"]
    },
    {
    "name": "signal_track_interval_extent_utc",
    "update": "[utcParse(signal_track_interval_input[0], '%Y-%m-%d'), utcParse(signal_track_interval_input[1], '%Y-%m-%d')]"
    },
    {
    "name": "signal_track_interval_date_sequence_utc",
    "update": "utcSequence('date', signal_track_interval_extent_utc[0], utcOffset('date', signal_track_interval_extent_utc[1], 1) )"
    }
],
"data": [
    {
    "name": "data_task_interval_input",
    "values": [
        {"task_id": 1, "date_opened": "2021-01-02 10:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-02 12:00"},
        {"task_id": 2, "date_opened": "2021-01-04 10:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-04 14:00"},
        {"task_id": 3, "date_opened": "2021-01-04 12:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-06 12:00"},
        {"task_id": 4, "date_opened": "2021-01-05 06:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-07 18:00"},
        {"task_id": 5, "date_opened": "2021-01-05 16:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-07 08:00"},
        {"task_id": 6, "date_opened": "2021-01-06 08:00", "date_closed": null},
        {"task_id": 7, "date_opened": "2021-01-06 12:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-07 08:00"},
        {"task_id": 8, "date_opened": "2021-01-06 14:00", "date_closed": null},
        {"task_id": 9, "date_opened": "2021-01-07 11:00", "date_closed": null},
        {"task_id": 10, "date_opened": "2021-01-07 13:00", "date_closed": "2021-01-07 15:00"}
    ],
    "transform": [
        {
        "type": "formula",
        "as": "task_opened_datetime_utc",
        "expr": "utcParse(datum['date_opened'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"
        },
        {
        "type": "formula",
        "as": "task_closed_datetime_utc",
        "expr": "utcParse(datum['date_closed'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"
        },
        {
        "type": "formula",
        "as": "task_opened_date_utc",
        "expr": "utcFloor(['year', 'month', 'date'], datum['task_opened_datetime_utc'])"
        },
        {
        "type": "formula",
        "as": "task_closed_date_utc",
        "expr": "datum['task_closed_datetime_utc'] ? utcFloor(['year', 'month', 'date'], datum['task_closed_datetime_utc']) : null"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "data_task_date_sequence_utc",
    "source": "data_task_interval_input",
    "transform": [
        {
        "type": "formula",
        "as": "date_sequence_array",
        "expr": "utcSequence('date', datum['task_opened_date_utc'], utcOffset('date', datum['task_closed_date_utc'] ? datum['task_closed_date_utc'] : signal_track_interval_extent_utc[1], 1))"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "data_task_hours_by_date_utc",
    "source": "data_task_date_sequence_utc",
    "transform": [
        {
        "type": "flatten",
        "fields": ["date_sequence_array"],
        "as": ["task_date_utc"]
        },
        {
        "type": "formula",
        "as": "is_task_date_opened",
        "expr": "time(datum['task_date_utc']) == time(datum['task_opened_date_utc'])"
        },
        {
        "type": "formula",
        "as": "is_task_date_closed",
        "expr": "datum['task_closed_date_utc'] && (time(datum['task_date_utc']) == time(datum['task_closed_date_utc']))"
        },
        {
        "type": "formula",
        "as": "task_hours",
        "expr": "datum['is_task_date_opened'] && datum['is_task_date_closed'] ? utchours(datum['task_closed_datetime_utc']) - utchours(datum['task_opened_datetime_utc']) : datum['is_task_date_opened'] ? 24 - utchours(datum['task_opened_datetime_utc']) : datum['is_task_date_closed'] ? utchours(datum['task_closed_datetime_utc']) : 24"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "data_task_hours_aggregate_by_date_utc",
    "source": "data_task_hours_by_date_utc",
    "transform": [
        {
        "type": "aggregate",
        "as": ["task_count", "task_hours_average", "task_hours_total"],
        "groupby": ["task_date_utc"],
        "fields": ["task_id", "task_hours", "task_hours"],
        "ops": ["count", "mean", "sum"]
        }
    ]
    }
],
"scales": [
    {
    "name": "scale_lookup_aggregate_fieldname",
    "type": "ordinal",
    "domain": [
        "Number of tasks",
        "Average hours per task",
        "Total hours for all tasks"
    ],
    "range": ["task_count", "task_hours_average", "task_hours_total"]
    },
    {
    "name": "scale_x",
    "type": "band",
    "range": "width",
    "padding": 0.05,
    "round": true,
    "domain": {"signal": "signal_track_interval_date_sequence_utc"}
    },
    {
    "name": "scale_y",
    "type": "linear",
    "range": "height",
    "domain": {
        "data": "data_task_hours_aggregate_by_date_utc",
        "field": {
        "signal": "scale('scale_lookup_aggregate_fieldname', signal_aggregate_type)"
        }
    },
    "zero": true,
    "nice": true
    }
],
"axes": [
    {
    "orient": "bottom",
    "scale": "scale_x",
    "formatType": "utc",
    "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
    "labelAlign": "right",
    "labelAngle": -45,
    "title": "Date"
    },
    {
    "orient": "left",
    "scale": "scale_y",
    "format": "d",
    "tickMinStep": 1,
    "title": {"signal": "signal_aggregate_type"}
    }
],
"marks": [
    {
    "type": "rect",
    "from": {"data": "data_task_hours_aggregate_by_date_utc"},
    "encode": {
        "update": {
        "x": {"scale": "scale_x", "field": "task_date_utc"},
        "width": {"scale": "scale_x", "band": 1},
        "y": {
            "scale": "scale_y",
            "field": {
            "signal": "scale('scale_lookup_aggregate_fieldname', signal_aggregate_type)"
            }
        },
        "y2": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0},
        "fill": {"value": "steelblue"},
        "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{'Date': utcFormat(datum['task_date_utc'], '%a %b %d, %Y'), 'Number of tasks': datum['task_count'], 'Average hours per task': format(datum['task_hours_average'], '.1f'), 'Total hours for all tasks': datum['task_hours_total']}"
        }
        },
        "hover": {"fill": {"value": "red"}}
    }
    }
]
};



let vegaView = new vega.View(vega.parse(vegaSpec), {
        renderer:  'canvas',  // renderer (canvas or svg)
        container: '#vis',   // parent DOM container
        hover:     true       // enable hover processing
    });
vegaView.runAsync();
```